# Reading/Writing files using nothing but a handle

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-7, handle

A question came up at work where I am not sure of the answer.  Suppose there is a handle, within a process, to a directory.  The handle has RW set and lets say it points to the desktop.  Is there a way to use nothing but the handle in order to read or write files to the desktop?

Thanks for any ideas!

Edit: To clarify, this is on Windows and is a File handle pointing at the desktop.  Lets assume you already know the value of the handle and are looking to use it within the same process in order to read/write files to the desktop that it points at.  Any code is allowed, including the Windows API.

Comment: What sort of handle are you talking about? An OS handle? If so, what OS?

Comment: A handle to a directory is no good. In order to write files you need a handle to a file. And if any Win API calls are allowed then you can of course do anything. This is not a real question.

Comment: To rephrase: you have a handle to an unknown directory and you want to find out which directory it is pointing to so that you can write a file to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the directory handle to obtain the pathname, append the file you want to write onto the end of it, then use [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C and C++ have no notion of a directory, and thus the strict answer is **no**.

To say anything more, we need more information. What do you mean by a handle? What are the platforms/libraries you are allowed work with?

Also, it's not clear what you mean by "nothing but the handle." Functions are not the handle; are you allowed to call functions?